# Where to find a specific version of a .NET Framework DLL (to examine in Reflector)

Tags: .net, debugging, reflector

I'd like to get hold of version 2.0.50727.832 of System.Windows.Forms.dll - does anyone know where I can find it, *without* installing the correpsonding version of the .NET Framework?

**Background:** A customer has just reported a crash in my product.  I believe it's due to [a bug in a previous version of the .NET framework](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=117180), which is fixed in the version I'm running.

I think I know how to work around the bug, but I could know for sure if I could load the customer's version of the DLL into Reflector and examine the offending code.

**Edit:** I'd rather not ask the customer to send it, because I don't know for certain that doing so would be legal.

Comment: Don't forget it's likely the new version of the DLL depends on other libraries in that same version of the .NET framework.

Comment: @Rushyo: Would that prevent my loading it into Reflector?

Comment: Answering my own question to Rushyo: No, it doesn't. I can load it into Reflector just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out, or at least I have for version 2.0.50727.42:

- Download the .NET 2.0 installer from here: [OldVersion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/download_.Net_Framework_2.0.html)
- Open `netframework20.exe` in a Zip tool and unzip it
- Run `msiexec /a netfx.msi /qb TARGETDIR="C:\Some-Folder"` to unpack the MSI
- System.Windows.Forms.dll is now in `C:\Some-Folder\Win\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath`

Cool.  I can now see Microsoft's silly off-by-one bug in the old version, and not in my current version.  I can safely assume that the bug is in the customer's version as well, and I now know for sure that my workaround will work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Have your user look in the following folder:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

The dll should be there,  you can have them use the properties dialog to check the version.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: I'd rather not ask the customer to send it, because I don't know for certain that doing so would be legal.

Comment: I do not see a licensing issue with this.  You are the author of the program.  Downloading the .net framework from Microsoft is free.  You have a legal license of Visual Studio and it is your application.