# How do I get specific versions of the .NET runtime for use in windbg?

Tags: .net, dll, version, windbg

I am debugging an old process dump from one of our servers. It was created about a month ago. To work with SOS, I need version 2.0.50727.4016 of mscorwks.dll and mscordacwks.dll for the AMD64 architecture.

Is there some official place to get these dlls? I found [one question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349708/where-to-find-a-specific-version-of-a-net-framework-dll-to-examine-in-reflector) that somewhat addresses the issue, but the solution seems a bit hackish and roundabout.

What is the official Microsoft channel for getting old framework dlls?

Comment: @Ryan: I asked the question you're linking to; I never found any better way to do it than the answer in that question. Sadly, that method is only useful for the versions of the framework on `oldversions.com`.  I'd love to hear of a better solution.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Thanks for the feedback. If nothing comes up, I'll see what my Microsoft rep can do. I'll post their response if I get one.

Comment: try ".load wow64exts" and "!sw" commands. before ".loadby sos mscorwks"

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35257986/newbie-question-about-win.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken this is an official .NET 2.0 x64 build. You can take it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B44A0000-ACF8-4FA1-AFFB-40E78D788B00&displaylang=en

Just install and find it under \Microsoft.NET